# Is there a way to express "dataframe with one column set to null" in R directly?

Tags: r

Consider the following idiom, where `foo` is some dataframe and `bar` is some column of `foo`.

Suppose I want use `foo` in some function `f`, but I want to use `foo` without the column `bar`. Here is one way to do it.

```
foo$bar <- NULL
f(foo)
```

However, this way requires me to change `foo`, which means that I would have to store `bar` in a separate variable and then restore it later. Here is another way to do it:

```
tfoo <- foo
tfoo$bar <- NULL
f(tfoo)
```

Here I am forced to make a separate variable to avoid changing `foo`.
My question is, is there a way to express the idea of "`foo` without `bar`" in a single line? That is, I want write something like, which is syntactically valid.

```
f(foo[,-bar])
```

Comment: Nope, that would only be syntactically valid if you had assigned a numeric value to an object in your global environment named "bar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f( foo[-grep("^bar$", names(foo)] )
```

You need to use numeric values for negative indexing. You can also use "negative" logical indexing"

```
f( foo[ !names(foo) %in% "bar" ] )
```

Also this is ok for interactive use:

```
f( subset(foo, select= -bar) )
```

You may see a response that suggests:

```
f( foo[ -which(names(foo) == "bar") ] )
```

... but generally one should avoid  `-which()` constructions.

Comment: +1 for all the options. I haven't yet gotten a chance to try all of these, but will comment when I figure out what works best for this.